# graphicx: scale parameter leaves original bounding box - ugly with hyperref

Tags: graphics, hyperref

With texlive 2016, I noticed that scaling an image does not also change its bounding box - the resulting bounding box will have dimensions akin to the original image.

This might leave "ugly" empty spaces on the top and right side of an image, but more importantly also messes up hyperlink hitboxes, if the *scaled* images are supposed to be hyperlinks.

[image: Visual representation, with <code>colorlinks=false</code> following a comment suggestion.]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage[xetex]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{float}

\newcommand\MYhyperrefoptions{bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,
pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,
colorlinks=false,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},
urlcolor={blue},
pdftitle={},
pdfsubject={},
pdfauthor={},
pdfkeywords={}}
\usepackage[\MYhyperrefoptions,breaklinks=true,xetex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \fbox{\href{http://crun.chy}{\includegraphics[scale=0.11]{a}}}
  \hspace*{5em}
  \fbox{\href{http://chun.ky}{\includegraphics[scale=0.13]{b}}}
  \caption{Click to enlarge}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \fbox{\href{http://crun.chy}{\includegraphics{a}}}
  \hspace*{5em}
  \fbox{\href{http://chun.ky}{\includegraphics{b}}}
  \caption{Click to enlarge}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Feel free to create two images like this: `convert -size 100x100 xc:#990000 a.eps; convert -size 100x100 xc:#009900 b.eps`

Obviously, the problem gets more pronounced with larger images.

I faintly remember that this used to work in 2013 or 2014 - what changed? Is this intended behavior?

I probably could try changing the viewport, but that would merely be a manual hack.

Interestingly, page 11 of [the graphicx documentation](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) does not seem to exhibit this problem.

Comment: With `colorlinks=false` you get annotation rectangles.

Comment: Options `viewport` or `trim` will not help, because they also change the image dimensions at TeX level. And such a hack will very likely stop working, if the image format is changed or the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that XeTeX does not take the PostScript image resolution into account.
The TeX macro level looks correct; the second image in a box:

```
\setbox2{\includegraphics[scale=.13]{b}}
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showbox2
```

gives the correct dimensions:

```
> \box2=
\hbox(13.04924+0.0)x13.04924
.\hbox(13.04924+0.0)x13.04924
..\hbox(13.04924+0.0)x13.04924
...\special{PSfile="b.eps" llx=0 lly=0 urx=100 ury=100 rwi=130 }
```

The boxes at TeX level can be visualized via `\fbox`. They look correct, see David Carlisle's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353276/16967). Therefore, I expect the error in the code that
calculate the link area and that seems to forget parameter `rwi` of PostScript images.

**Workaround:** Use a different image format than PostScript: PDF, PNG, ...

Comment: Either use `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop` or `epstopdf` to get the bounding box of the PostScript file as media box in the PDF file.

Comment: Weird, leaving out the `-dEPSCrop` option to `ps2pdf` produces a broken image (original image cropped in the lower left bottom, with huge white space surrounding it on the top and right side), while `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop`, `epstopdf` and ImageMagick's convert tool generate PDF files that "pure" `latex` doesn't like: `LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in a.pdf (no BoundingBox).`

`xelatex` has no problem with them, though, and both the visual bounding boxes as well as hyperref's bounding boxes are correct, as you said.

Comment: @Ionic The image is *not* broken, when using `ps2pdf` without `-dEPSCrop`. `ps2pdf` just uses the default paper size for the output medium; see Ghostscript option `-sPAPERSIZE=...`, how to set the paper size manually. Option `-dEPSCrop` looks for the bounding box specified in the EPS file.

Comment: Please ignore the stupid comment above. Even after many years of exposure to the *tex system I keep forgetting that the frontend of choice is `pdflatex`, not `latex`... if I want to get PDF files directly and support a wider range of image formats natively, without converting them into PS/EPS first.

PDF images have the correct bounding boxes with both `pdflatex` and `xelatex`. EPS seems to fail for only `xetex`.

Comment: I see the same problem when using latex + dvipdfmx. So it looks like (x)dvipdfmx bug.

Answer (score 2):

If I add `\fbox` to see the extent of the bounding box of the image, and process with a texlive 2016 xelatex I get

[image]

which looks Ok to me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage[xetex]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{float}

\newcommand\MYhyperrefoptions{bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,
pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,
colorlinks=true,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},
urlcolor={blue},
pdftitle={},
pdfsubject={},
pdfauthor={},
pdfkeywords={}}
\usepackage[\MYhyperrefoptions,breaklinks=true,xetex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \fbox{\href{http://crun.chy}{\includegraphics[scale=0.11]{a}}}
  \hspace*{5em}
  \fbox{\href{http://chun.ky}{\includegraphics[scale=0.13]{b}}}
  \caption{Click to enlarge}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \fbox{\href{http://crun.chy}{\includegraphics{a}}}
  \hspace*{5em}
  \fbox{\href{http://chun.ky}{\includegraphics{b}}}
  \caption{Click to enlarge}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\fbox` might be (I just reproduced that), but did you open up the resulting file in a PDF viewer and hover over the images and their surrounding space?

Comment: Compile with `colorlinks=false` to get annotation rectangles around the link area.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek that's odd, given that the tex box is shrunk as shown by fbox, can you see what hyperref is taking as the size? (I'll look later, but travelling today)