# Why is the link area in the image so small?

Tags: hyperref, texworks

I wrote code that applies a link to google.com to an image, such as:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{http://www.google.com}{\includegraphics[width=20em]{150x150.png}}
\href{http://www.google.com}{Google}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image used in above source code]

---

However, the result of the execution made a small linked area at the bottom left of the image. I want to extend the link area to the whole image. Also the link to the text is working. Here are screenshots of these results<sup>(The blue rectangle in the image shows the link area)</sup>:

[image: Result of execution the source code above]

I found the following similar topic, but the method described here did not solve my problem.

- [graphics - Hyperlink not surrounding figure - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416196/222704)

---

My environment is:

- Editor: TexWorks 0.6.2
- Typeset: pdfpLaTeX

Comment: if you are using pdflatex you should not confuse all packages by claiming that you use dvipdfmx.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought so too at first but the OP is using pdf**p**latex which seems to be an alias for `ptex2pdf`, which is a script for running `platex` followed by `dvipdfmx`.

Comment: Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353275/graphicx-scale-parameter-leaves-original-bounding-box-ugly-with-hyperref, but that does not really have an answer for the current setup.

Comment: Interestingly, for me it is the other way around. If I typeset with `(p)latex`+`dvipdfmx`, the link area is much bigger than the scaled graphics (I use `example-image.pdf`). But with `xelatex` the link is correctly sized.

Comment: @AlexG I guess the original bounding box is being used, and `example-image.pdf` is larger than 20em, while the OPs image is a png for which the bounding box is not used at all for the link rectangle.

Comment: @Marijn ah, I though it is a typo. Then it is probably the problem that no glyph is in the box. With xetex one could use `\XeTeXLinkBox`, but I don't think that it is also availabel for platex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Though it compiles without error, `\XeTeXLinkBox` doesn't seem to have any effect with `(p)latex`+`dvipdfmx.`

Comment: @AlexG you need to (re)define it (as you are doing in your answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdvipdfmx`, the back-end for `platex` and `xelatex`, needs typeset font glyphs in order to produce a link annotation with non-zero size in the PDF output. But included bitmap graphics don't provide them.

For this purpose, XeTeX provides the command `\XeTeXLinkBox{...}`, but it doesn't work with `(p)latex`+`dvipdfmx` for some reason.

So we define our own version here:

```latex
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*\LinkBox[1]{{%
  \font\tempa=pzdr scaled 1%
  \savebox0{#1}%
  \raisebox{-\dp0}[0pt][\dp0]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\tempa\char32}}%
  \usebox0%
  \raisebox{\ht0}[\ht0][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\tempa\char32}}%
}}

\begin{document}
\href{http://www.google.com}{\LinkBox{\includegraphics[width=20em]{example-grid-100x100bp.png}}}
\href{http://www.google.com}{Google}
\end{document}
```

It inserts tiny, invisible space characters from the Dingbats font at the lower left and the upper right corners of the included graphic file.

Answer (score 1):

dvipdfmx doesn't like it if there are no glyphs in the link box. It then doesn't correctly calculate the link box. This will perhaps change, there has been some discussion about it on the mailing list. Until then you can use the code hyperref offers for xetex for this case:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
  \font\XeTeXLink@font=pzdr at 1sp\relax
  \newcommand*{\XeTeXLink@space}{%
    \begingroup
      \XeTeXLink@font
      \@xxxii
    \endgroup
  }%
  \renewcommand{\XeTeXLinkBox}[1]{%
    \begingroup
      \leavevmode
      \sbox\z@{#1}%
      \begingroup
        \dimen@=\dp\z@
        \advance\dimen@\XeTeXLinkMargin
        \setbox\tw@=\llap{%
          \hb@xt@\XeTeXLinkMargin{%
            \lower\dimen@\hbox{\XeTeXLink@space}%
            \hss
          }%
        }%
        \dp\tw@=\dp\z@
        \ht\tw@=\ht\z@
        \copy\tw@
      \endgroup
      \copy\z@
      \dimen@=\ht\z@
      \advance\dimen@\XeTeXLinkMargin
      \setbox\tw@=\rlap{%
        \hb@xt@\XeTeXLinkMargin{%
          \hss
          \raise\dimen@\hbox{\XeTeXLink@space}%
        }%
      }%
      \dp\tw@=\dp\z@
      \ht\tw@=\ht\z@
      \copy\tw@
    \endgroup
  }%
\makeatother  
\begin{document}
\href{http://www.google.com}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{3d.png}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]